2D impulse physics engine broken polygon restitution
Been trying to make a simple 2D physics engine in C#. Followed a tutorial by "Two-Bit Coding" on youtube but noticed that squares, with two contact points would not bounce at all. Tracked that problem down to the impulses simply being too small when resolving the collisions.
Got some bounciness by multiplying the impulse by a value. This however is not a solution, since if the collision occurs very close to the body-center (on the middle an edge of a square) the impulse would be massive, causing the bounce to break the laws of energy conservation.
Tried another formula to resolve the collision, this time from Wikipedia.The formula is for 3D but I assumed it would work for 2D.
Formula from wikipedia
This is the C# implementation:
        public void Resolve_collision_wiki(in Physics_manifold contact)
        {
            Physics_body body_a = contact.body_a;
            Physics_body body_b = contact.body_b;
            Physics_vector normal = contact.normal;

            int contact_count = contact.contact_count;

            float e = 1;

            contact_list[0] = contact.contact_point_1;
            contact_list[1] = contact.contact_point_2;

            for (int i = 0; i < contact_count; i++)
            {
                Physics_vector ra = contact_list[i] - body_a.Position;
                Physics_vector rb = contact_list[i] - body_b.Position;

                center_a_contact_list[i] = ra;
                center_b_contact_list[i] = rb;


                Physics_vector relative_velocity = body_b.Linear_velocity - body_a.Linear_velocity + Physics_math.Cross_product(body_b.Angular_velocity, rb) - Physics_math.Cross_product(body_a.Angular_velocity, ra);

                //() first, then the dot product?
                float numerator = Physics_math.Dot_product(-(1 + e) * relative_velocity, normal);

                if (numerator < 0)
                    return;

                //https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/notesd2.pdf#page=16

                numerator /= body_a.inverse_mass + body_b.inverse_mass + Physics_math.Dot_product(Physics_math.Cross_product(body_a.inverse_inertia * Physics_math.Cross_product(ra, normal), ra) + Physics_math.Cross_product(body_b.inverse_inertia * Physics_math.Cross_product(rb, normal), rb), normal);
                numerator = MathF.Max(numerator, 0);

                j_list[i] = numerator;
            }


            //Applying in the first loop would make the second impulse be a bit off
            for (int i = 0; i < contact_count; i++)
            {
                body_a.Linear_velocity -= j_list[i] * body_a.inverse_mass * normal;
                body_a.Angular_velocity -=  Physics_math.Cross_product(center_a_contact_list[i], normal * j_list[i]) * body_a.inverse_inertia;

                body_b.Linear_velocity += j_list[i] * body_b.inverse_mass * normal;
                body_b.Angular_velocity +=  Physics_math.Cross_product(center_b_contact_list[i], normal * j_list[i]) * body_b.inverse_inertia;
            }
        }

The dot product and 2D cross product implementation:
        public static float Dot_product(Physics_vector a, Physics_vector b)
        {
            return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y;
        }

        public static float Cross_product(Physics_vector a, Physics_vector b)
        {
            return a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x;
        }

        public static Physics_vector Cross_product(float a, Physics_vector v)
        {
            return new Physics_vector(-a * v.y, a * v.x);
        }


But the bounce height still changes dramatically when I move to contact points closer to each other, and gets lower when the contact points are farther apart. Furthermore, an e value of 1 won't give a perfectly elastic collision for squares like it does for circles.
